# Java generics for hiding type specific implementation?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to create an API so that the implementation and class names are not needed when other programmers use my service.  The service performs a variety of operations on "items" but the main contributing factor to how the service should deal with a request for an item is based on the user type.  So far I have an Interface (`Item`) and an implementing service (`ItemService`) and then several user type classes that extend from this (e.g. `CompanyItemService`).  The user types also have a structure with the super class being `User` and subclasses such as `Company`:

```
public class ItemService<T extends User> extends Item {
    User user;
    public ItemService(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean belongsToUser() {
        //Check all records
    }
}

public class CompanyItemService<T extends Company> extends ItemService<Company> {
    public CompanyItemService(Company user) {
        super(user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean belongsToUser() {
        //Check company specific records
    }
}

public class User {
    //Common user stuff
}

public class Company extends User {
    //Company specific stuff
}
```

And so I want to be able to use my service with a call like:

```
User company = new Company();
//stuff
Item item = new ItemService<Company>(company)
item.belongsToUser();
```

However when I do this the method in the `ItemService` gets called instead of the overriding method in the `CompanyItemService`.  Is it possible to get this overriding method without needed to know it belongs in the class `CompanyItemService`?

Cheers,

Alexei Blue.

The general idea to all this is that when another user type is invented another user specific service can be added if needed leaving the existing code untouched.  And also if there are lots of user types I only want people using the API to have to remember to use `ItemService` and for generics to do the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the *[abstract factory pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)* In short, you need a static method someplace which knows about all the possible `ItemService` subclasses and, given an `Item` object or a `Class` which is a subclass of `User`, returns an instance of the correct `ItemService` subclass. In other words, something like

```
public static ItemService<?> instance(Class<? extends User> c) {
    if (c == Customer.class)
        return new CustomerItemService();
    else if (c == Employee.class)
        return new EmployeeItemService();
    ...
}
```

Then you can say

```
ItemService<?> service = ItemService.instance(Customer.class);
```

Alternatively, you could build a map:

```
Map<Class<? extends User>, Class<? extends ItemService>> services = 
    new HashMap<Class<? extends User>, Class<? extends ItemService>>() {{
    put(Customer.class, CustomerItemService.class);
    put(Employee.class, EmployeeItemService.class);
    // more...
}};
```

Then `instance()` could just look like

```
ItemService<? extends User> instance(Class<? extends User> c) {
    return services.get(c);
}
```

Comment: Also I should a Map<Class<? extends User>, Class<? extends UserService>> for that implementation :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ernest, so hypothetically if I have say huge number of User types all with their own implementation I would need to specify each one individually I guess?

Comment: @AlexeiBlue  -- as @helios said, you could use a `Map` to hold the data about the pairs of classes, so the code itself would remain small. It's possible to get *very* fancy and read that sort of data from a properties file at runtime, or offer a `registerItemService()` method which let you install additional ones at runtime from code. The simple `if-then` is fine if there are just a few types, though.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example of how to build the map based on my example please?  The generics are making my eyes go fuzzy :S  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code work as it should work. You create an instance of ItemService:

```
Item item = new ItemService<Company>(company);
```

If you call belongsToUser() method of ItemService will be called.
You should create instance of CompanyItemService to call it method.

Comment: Tnk you for your answer alexey28, but that's what I'm trying to hide.  My understanding of generics isn't fantastic but I guessed that this was one of its many uses.

Comment: Generics just helps you do not cast manually Float floatVal = (Float) objVal. And that all. You cannot create instance based on generic type as you want it here. You should have some registry - Map that has a key Class and value - instance of your class that should be created (for singleton) or constructor calling via reflection for example (for prototype).